# Bitcoin Core - Bought bitcoin to a 'sending address', what can I now do, nothing is showing up in my transactions

Tags: bitcoin-core

As the question says, on the wallet, bitcoin core, under file you can find 'sending addresses' and 'receiving addresses'. In a moment of absolute stupidity I copied one of the sending addresses when buying some bitcoin. The transaction is marked as having occured on bittylicious but no transactions appear on my bitcoin wallet - what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you provided one from your sending instead of receiving consider those coins donated. Your wallet only shows transactions on addresses you own.

What you can do is try to figure out what address you provided them. I've never used the service you mentioned but they probably have the transaction ID available. Once you find out the address try to remember what you used that address for in the past. Your coins might be on an exchange or website you used before.

Comment: thanks for the response, I know what address I provided, I have used it once in the past to send bitcoin, does this mean they have been sent to the same person i sent to last time?

Comment: @DBC: Yes, you send them to the owner of that sending address.